# How to hide header and footer on certain react pages?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have it where my header and footer wrap the outlet of my pages but I would like the header and footer to be hidden on certain pages such as the customer and admin dashboard. What would be the best approach for this?

```
const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    // Parent taking in element of entire app
    <Route path='/' element={<App />}>
      <Route index={true} path='/' element={<Home />} />
      <Route index={true} path='/register' element={<Register />} />
      <Route index={true} path='/login' element={<Login />} />
      <Route index={true} path='/logcheck' element={<EnterEmail />} />
      <Route index={true} path='/precheck' element={<Precheck />} />
      <Route index={true} path='/plans' element={<PlansPage />} />

      <Route path='' element={<PrivateRoute />}>
        <Route path='/dashboard' element={<CustomerDash />}/>
      </Route>
    </Route>
  )
)

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
)





function App() {

  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <main>
        <Outlet />
      </main>
      <Footer />
      <ToastContainer />
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by using a wrapper like *this* :

```
<Route index={true} path='/' element={<HeaderAllowed><Home/></HeaderAllowed>} />

export const HeaderAllowed = ({ children }) => {
    return (
        <>
            <HeaderComponent>
                {children}
            </HeaderComponent>
        </>
    );
}
```

Comment: export const HeaderAllowed = ({ children }) => { return ( <><HeaderComponent> {children}  </HeaderComponent></> ); }

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do this, but the simplest one is Conditional Rendering. I mean, conditionally rendering the header and footer based on the current route.

> You can use 'useLocation' hook to get the current route.

I assume you don't want the header and footer on following routes:

> '/register', '/login' and '/logcheck'

Here's how you can do this.

```
import React from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Navbar, Footer, ToastContainer } from './components';  // adjust

function App() {
  const location = useLocation();
  const hideHeaderFooter = ['/register', '/login', '/logcheck'].includes(location.pathname);

  return (
    <>
      {!hideHeaderFooter && <Navbar />}
      <main>
        <Outlet />
      </main>
      {!hideHeaderFooter && <Footer />}
      <ToastContainer />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```